# Would it be okay for me to assign variables then reference them right after?

Tags: java, variables

I'm using an online compiler right now, and can't access a real one. Is using variables like this okay?

```
{
    int hourWork = (sqFt) / 14;
}
{
    int gallonUse = hourWork / 8;
}
{
    int gallonPrice = gallonUse * 1;
}
int workPrice = (hourWork * 18) + gallonPrice;
```

Like, is it okay to reference a variable then immediately use it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, but why the many curly braces?

Comment: when do you plan to use them if not afterwards? (why so many braces?)

Comment: You cannot access any of them because you added all those useless blocks with curly braces. A local variable is only accessible inside the  block it was declared.

Comment: "I'm using an online compiler right now" if that compiler isn't able to answer your question, it's not worth using.

Answer (score 3):

What you posted will not work because of scoping issues. you need to take out brackets.

```
int hourWork = (sqFt) / 14;
int gallonUse = hourWork / 8;
int gallonPrice = gallonUse * 1;
int workPrice = (hourWork * 18) + gallonPrice;
```

Comment: I use curly brackets sometimes to achieve the opposite: Hide temporary variables from the code below.

Comment: @Stefan but these aren't temporary variables with respect to the code below.

Comment: @Stefan Even so, that is *very* rare. I can't think of a situation where such code wouldn't be better structured by extracting that *code below* into a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a trick question, designed fool a novice.

The variables are scoped to their blocks, so `hourWork` and `gallonPrice` are not accessible on the `workPrice` line.

See also [Variable Scope in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope)